# Why does my GUI fail to appear on the page?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Grid extends JFrame{
    public Grid(){
        super("Pathfinding Algorithms");
        setContentPane(new drawGrid());
        setSize(1920,1080);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    class drawGrid extends JPanel { 
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(0,50,1920,50);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Grid();
    }
}
```

For some reason, nothing is being displayed whenever I run this code. I receive no errors and I get no output messages.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code works for me. The whole screen is painted gray and a black, horizontal line runs across the the entire screen near the top of the the screen.

Comment: Same report as @Abra. Having said that, there are a number of problems & a few redundancies in that code, which mean the behaviour may not be consistent access machines.

Comment: As to those problems & redundancies: 1) There is no need to extend `JFrame` here. Just use a plain instance of one. 2) `drawGrid` should be named `DrawGrid` to match common Java nomenclature. 3) `setSize(1920,1080);` is redundant, given `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` 4) `setVisible(true);` should be immediately after `pack()`. 5) `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` Add the `@Override` notation for compile time checking of method name and arguments. 6) In any overridden method, always call the `super()` method first. 7) `new Grid();` should be called on the EDT.

Comment: .. 8) Given the call to `setUndecorated(true);` it probably makes more sense to use a `JWindow`. --- I suspect the problems come from points 4 and 7, but implement them all and get back to us. Alternately, toss this code out as the mess it is and start again, *after* having completed the 'creating a GUI' trail of the Java tutorial.

Comment: What is the "EDT"?

Comment: *"What is the "EDT"?"* What is [a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=edt+java)? Tip: Whenever you hear a term or abbreviation you do not understand, add it to the name of the language (e.g. 'java') and pop that query into a search engine. Another tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow a tutorial to learn the basics of Swing. [Oracle provides one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) free-of-cost.

There you will find [this example code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java) to compare to your code.

In that example code you’ll find the `main` method makes this call:

```java
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
});
```

## *Swing* thread

Every Swing app has a thread dedicated to the GUI, the [*event dispatching thread (EDT)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) thread mentioned here in the Comments. Drawing, tracking the user's inputs with mouse and keyboard, responding to window dragging/resizing, and all other **on-screen work *must* be performed on that thread** dedicated to Swing.

In contrast, you code is running on the main thread.

That `invokeLater` call seen above is a way to get your GUI creation code to run on the Swing thread. So you could modify your code like this:

```java
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Grid() ;
            }
});
```

However, I suggest you study that tutorial and other examples for better ways of how to work with Swing. For example, it is generally best to avoid doing work unnecessarily in constructors as seen in your code snippet. And pay attention to issues listed in [Comment by Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543742/why-does-my-gui-fail-to-appear-on-the-page#comment124701116_70543742).

---

By the way, Swing is fully supported but is in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode).

You may want to consider the alternative, [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) ([OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/)). JavaFX is being actively developed, with a release every six months synchronized to Java releases. Development is led by the [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/) company in cooperation with Oracle Corp. [as a sub-project on](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx) the [OpenJDK project](https://openjdk.java.net/).

Same threading rules apply to JavaFX, where a thread is dedicated to the GUI. Never access or manipulate a GUI widget in either Swing or JavaFX/OpenJFX from another thread.